# convertion objet to array

Tags: python, arrays

I need to convert that in array

My result look like

```
[array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]),
array([1916.924,0.,0.,0.,267.08,11.156647, 264.044, 2629.504, 170.109,3883.039, 2842.796])]
```

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: Also your arrays are varying in length how do you suppose to handle them? Concatenate them?

Comment: is your above result  is string or an array

Comment: The OP should provide the full context of the problem statement and the issue they are facing. This is an ambiguous question with no defined parameters to work on. The community cannot help unless we know the details of the problem being faced. Just like a doctor cannot diagnose without knowing the ailments

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for the syntax to concatenate a list of numpy arrays into a 1D numpy array, you can do `numpy.concatenate(test)`, where `test`is your list. See the doc (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) for less basic use.